# SvelteKit App immediately exits without error

Tags: node.js, express, svelte, sveltekit

When I try to start my SvelteKit app, the node process just exits without any error code.

I've found something weird in the generated files which appears to be the culprit:

In a `handler-[some id].js` (which exports the `handle` function I actually use in the Express wrapper to the app):

```
...
console.log('await server init');
await server.init({ env: process.env });
console.log('after server init');
...
```

(I added the console logs)

This code is at the top level (around line 25_000 in the file), and the first log runs but then the second never runs.

Inside that `server.init` function, it runs this: `await import('./hooks.server-18c873a6.js')`.

Now interestingly, this file imports (using `import x from 'y'` syntax) another file, which then imports (same style) from the original `handler-[some id].js`, however surely there is no way that this can work as the original handle file has a top level await in??

I can't figure out why this `await server.init({ env: process.env });` is generated by SvelteKit, but when I manually remove the `await`, it works fine!

Any ideas why this is happening? I'd rather not have to keep manually editing the generated files in order to get my application to run haha.

I should also add that it worked fine before, and I can't figure out what I changed as I reverted back to a commit I am sure works (as it is currently running live) and it still has this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try roll back to previous `adapter-node` version with `npm i @sveltejs/adapter-node@1.2.4`

There is an open issue that may be causing the problem:

https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/10299

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much, everything seems to be working now :)